# How to use try catch purposefully?

Tags: android, database, try-catch, android-room, android-database

I'm using try catch like below code to avoid crash app when using database query :

```
AppExecutors.getsInstance().diskIO().execute(()->{
    try{
    database.classDao().insertClass(new ClassEntry(className,classDay));

    }catch(SQLiteException e){
    Log.e("TAG","saveClassToDatabase: " +e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

But I have many queries like this in my app and that means to I have to use many try catch.

**My question :** Is there a way to write try catch once and use it everywhere to handle queries error ?

**Note :** I use room database.

Comment: You wouldn't want to do that.  Do you really have 1 generic way of handling errors that you always want to do no matter what?  Of course not.  It doesn't make sense to do that.

Comment: Also, AppExecutors is part of a dead library.  There hasn't been an update to it since 2018.  If you're following a tutorial, I suggest you look for some more modern examples-  it wasn't a major library even at its peak, and it's been dead for a while

Comment: What library do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using try/catch and possibly finally should be not be needed that much, if at all, when using Room as:-

- SQL is typically checked for validity/correctness at compile time
- Dao methods/functions can be written to handle typical insert/update/delete conflicts using the onCoflict parameter of the respective annotation

  - e.g. `@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)`, will ignore NOT NULL, CHECK (not really applicable to Room) and UNIQUE constraint conflicts.
  - this can be effective if the appropriate value (long for inserts, int for updates and deletions) is returned e.g. (java)

    - `long insert(TheObjectType the object);` where the long returned will be the rowid (positive) if the row was inserted or -1 if not (an exception would be if forcing -1 as a value).
    - `int delete(TheObjectType object)` where the value returned will be the number of affected rows, so if 0 nothing was deleted. Same for update except obviously 0 = nothing updated.

Note that the onConflict action (IGNORE as above) does not apply to Foreign Key constraints if used. These are perhaps a potential for using catch/try although checks could be undertaken prior to insertion (deletion and updates can maintain the referential integrity automatically using `onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE` and `onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE` respectively).

If you really need to have a single catch/try then you could not utilise Room's convenience methods (`@Insert`, '@Update', '@Delete' and `@Query` but instead use (although many would say misuse) `@RawQuery` **this is not a recommendation**.

Perhaps consider this demo which covers some of the above:-

The `@Entity` annotated class **School**:-

```
@Entity(
        indices = {
                @Index(value = "schoolName", unique = true)
        }
)
class School {
    @PrimaryKey
    Long schoolId=null;
    String schoolName;

    School(){}
    @Ignore
    School(String schoolName) {
        this.schoolName = schoolName;
    }
    School(Long schoolId, String schoolName) {
        this.schoolId = schoolId;
        this.schoolName = schoolName;
    }
}
```

- note the UNIQUE index on the School Name.

an `@Dao` annotated class **AllDao** :-

```
@Dao
abstract class AllDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract long insert(School school);

    @RawQuery
    abstract Cursor rawQueryIntoCursor(SimpleSQLiteQuery simpleSQLiteQuery);
    @RawQuery
    abstract long rawQueryIntoLong(SimpleSQLiteQuery simpleSQLiteQuery);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM school")
    abstract List<School> getAllSchools();

}
```

- Note the use of onConflict (set to IGNORE, so duplicates would be ignored when inserting)
- Also note the 2 `@RawQuery`s
- How these are used will be made apparent in the invoking activity (below)

an `@Database` annotated abstract class **TheDatabase** :-

```
@Database(entities = {School.class}, exportSchema = false, version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    abstract AllDao getAllDao();

    private static volatile TheDatabase instance;
    static TheDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance==null) {
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase.class,"the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

- Note allows running on the main thread for brevity.

Finally the activity code that demonstrates much that has been said above (not all though) in the answer; **MainActivity** :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final String TAG = "DBINFO";

    private static String insertSchoolSQL = "INSERT INTO School (schoolName) VALUES (?)";
    private static String safeInsertSchoolSQL = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO School (schoolName) VALUES(?)";
    TheDatabase db;
    AllDao dao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this);
        dao = db.getAllDao();

        /* Stage 1 insert some schools using the convenience method */
        /* Note that a duplicate does not need try/catch due to IGNORE */
        /* see below for the insertSchool method */
        insertSchool(new School("School1"));
        insertSchool(new School("School2"));
        insertSchool(new School("School1")); /*<<<<<<<<< OOOPS duplicate */
        /* get All the schools and write to the Log */
        logAllSchools("-STAGE001");

        /* Stage 2 insert some schools via the actionRawQuery method which can action many
            SQL functions (limitation is obtaining results but could be enhanced)
         */
        actionRawQuery(true,safeInsertSchoolSQL,new String[]{"School3"});
        actionRawQuery(true,insertSchoolSQL,new String[]{"School4"});
        actionRawQuery(true,safeInsertSchoolSQL,new String[]{"School3"}); /*<<<<<<<<<< OOOPS duplicate  but NO EXCEPTION */
        actionRawQuery(true,insertSchoolSQL,new String[]{"School3"}); /*<<<<<<<<<< OOOPS duplicate */
        /* Again get All the schools and write to the Log */
        logAllSchools("-STAG002");

        /* other things that can be done with raw query */
        Cursor csr = dao.rawQueryIntoCursor(new SimpleSQLiteQuery("PRAGMA user_version",null));
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
        long queryResult = dao.rawQueryIntoLong(new SimpleSQLiteQuery("PRAGMA user_version",null));
        Log.d(TAG,"Result from rawQueryIntoLong was " + queryResult);
    }

    boolean insertSchool(School school) {
        boolean rv = true;
        if (dao.insert(school) != -1) {
            Log.d(TAG,"School successfully inserted.");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG,"School not inserted (duplicate or NOT NULL column is null)");
            rv = false;
        }
        return rv;
    }

    void logAllSchools(String tagSuffix) {
        for (School s: dao.getAllSchools()) {
            Log.d(TAG+tagSuffix,"SchoolName is " + s.schoolName + " ID is " + s.schoolId);
        }
    }

    void actionRawQuery(boolean returnAsLong,String SQL, String[] queryArgs) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String s: queryArgs) {
            sb.append("\n\t\t").append(s);
        }
        try {
            if (returnAsLong) {
                dao.rawQueryIntoLong(new SimpleSQLiteQuery(SQL,queryArgs));
            } else {
                dao.rawQueryIntoCursor(new SimpleSQLiteQuery(SQL,queryArgs));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Issue encountered attempting RawQuery. \n\tSQL=" + SQL+ "\n\tArguments passed=" + sb + "\n\tException Encountered:-" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**Results**

```
2022-08-21 19:53:33.228 D/DBINFO: School successfully inserted.
2022-08-21 19:53:33.229 D/DBINFO: School successfully inserted.
2022-08-21 19:53:33.242 D/DBINFO: School not inserted (duplicate or NOT NULL column is null)
2022-08-21 19:53:33.251 D/DBINFO-STAGE001: SchoolName is School1 ID is 1
2022-08-21 19:53:33.251 D/DBINFO-STAGE001: SchoolName is School2 ID is 2


2022-08-21 19:53:33.256 E/SQLiteQuery: exception: UNIQUE constraint failed: School.schoolName (code 2067 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE); query: INSERT INTO School (schoolName) VALUES (?)
2022-08-21 19:53:33.256 D/DBINFO: Issue encountered attempting RawQuery. 
        SQL=INSERT INTO School (schoolName) VALUES (?)
        Arguments passed=
            School3
        Exception Encountered:-UNIQUE constraint failed: School.schoolName (code 2067 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE)
2022-08-21 19:53:33.257 D/DBINFO-STAG002: SchoolName is School1 ID is 1
2022-08-21 19:53:33.258 D/DBINFO-STAG002: SchoolName is School2 ID is 2
2022-08-21 19:53:33.258 D/DBINFO-STAG002: SchoolName is School3 ID is 3
2022-08-21 19:53:33.258 D/DBINFO-STAG002: SchoolName is School4 ID is 4


2022-08-21 19:53:33.258 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@97d7d39
2022-08-21 19:53:33.259 I/System.out: 0 {
2022-08-21 19:53:33.259 I/System.out:    user_version=1
2022-08-21 19:53:33.259 I/System.out: }
2022-08-21 19:53:33.259 I/System.out: <<<<<


2022-08-21 19:53:33.261 D/DBINFO: Result from rawQueryIntoLong was 1
```

As can be seen the first Stage insert 2 rows and the third was IGNORED and that no exceptions were encountered.

The second stage attempted to insert 4 rows using the `actionRawQuery` method (a single try/catch). Thus 2 duplicate attempts one shows the `OR IGNORE` (what Room codes when `onConflict = OnConflictStategy.IGNORE` is coded). The second duplicate, because `OR IGNORE` is not coded, results in a trapped/caught exception.

The following is 2 other uses of `@RawQuery` that retrieves the database version (user_version) using the `PRAGMA user_version`. The first returns the result as a Cursor the second as a long.

- This works, for long, because PRAGMA user_version will return just the one value. An exception would occur, if more than one value were returned.

**Additional**

It would be possible to extend the relatively simple **actionRawQuery** method so that it can handle multiple queries. For example:-

First a new class **RawQuery** :-

```
class RawQuery {
   private boolean resultTypeLongElseCursor;
   private Cursor resultCusror;
   private Long resultLong;
   private String actionSQL;
   private String[] actionArgs;
   private SimpleSQLiteQuery simpleSQLiteQuery;
   private Exception exception;

   RawQuery(
           boolean resultTypeLongElseCusror,
           String actionSQL,
           String[] actionArgs
   ) {
       this.resultTypeLongElseCursor = resultTypeLongElseCusror;
       this.actionSQL = actionSQL;
       this.actionArgs = actionArgs;
       this.resultCusror = null;
       this.resultLong = null;
   }

    public Cursor getResultCusror() {
        return resultCusror;
    }

    public void setResultCusror(Cursor resultCusror) {
        this.resultCusror = resultCusror;
    }

    public Long getResultLong() {
        return resultLong;
    }

    public void setResultLong(Long resultLong) {
        this.resultLong = resultLong;
    }

    public boolean isResultTypeLongElseCursor() {
        return resultTypeLongElseCursor;
    }

    public void setResultTypeLongElseCursor(boolean resultTypeLongElseCursor) {
        this.resultTypeLongElseCursor = resultTypeLongElseCursor;
    }

    public void setActionArgs(String[] actionArgs) {
        this.actionArgs = actionArgs;
    }

    public String[] getActionArgs() {
        return actionArgs;
    }

    public void setActionSQL(String actionSQL) {
        this.actionSQL = actionSQL;
    }

    public String getActionSQL() {
        return actionSQL;
    }

    public SimpleSQLiteQuery getSimpleSQLiteQuery() {
        return new SimpleSQLiteQuery(actionSQL,actionArgs);
    }

    public void setException(Exception exception) {
        this.exception = exception;
    }

    public Exception getException() {
        return exception;
    }
}
```

An array of these could then be actioned by a new method such as **actionMultipleRawQueries**

```
boolean actionMultipleRawQueries(
        RawQuery[] queries,
        boolean forceNotInTransaction,
        TheDatabase db, //<<<<< SHOULD REFLECT the @Database annotated class
        boolean logException,
        String logTag,
        boolean includeExceptionStacktrace
) {
    SupportSQLiteDatabase suppDb = db.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase();
    boolean successful = false;
    if (!forceNotInTransaction) {
        Log.d(logTag,"Beginning Transaction");
        suppDb.beginTransaction();
    }

    try {
        /* NOTE rawQueryIntoLong and rawQueryIntoCursor would be defined in the respective
            @Dao annotated class
         */
        for (RawQuery query: queries) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (query.getActionArgs() != null) {
                for (String s : query.getActionArgs()) {
                    sb.append("\n\t\t Arg is ").append(s);
                }
            }
            Log.d(logTag,"Actioning Raw Query " + query.getActionSQL() + " args are:" + sb);
            if (query.isResultTypeLongElseCursor()) {
                query.setResultLong(dao.rawQueryIntoLong(query.getSimpleSQLiteQuery()));
            } else {
                query.setResultCusror(dao.rawQueryIntoCursor(query.getSimpleSQLiteQuery()));
            }
        }
        /* Only set the transaction as successful IF all queries run OK */
        if (!forceNotInTransaction) {
            Log.d(logTag,"Setting Transaction Successful.");
            suppDb.setTransactionSuccessful();
        }
        successful = true;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (logException) {
            Log.d(logTag,"Action Multiple Raw Queries Exception:-\n\t" + e.getMessage());
            if (includeExceptionStacktrace) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    finally {
        /* Always end the transaction NOTING THAT
            if an exception occurred then doing so rolls back (undoes) any changes
            otherwise changes will be applied (i.e. if no exception)
         */
        if (!forceNotInTransaction) {
            Log.d(logTag,"Ending Transaction.");
            suppDb.endTransaction();
        }
    }
    return successful;
}
```

To test/demonstrate the above, then Adding the following code to the activity:-

```
    /* Example using actionMultipleRawQueries  will be rolled back as deigned to try inserting duplicates*/
    RawQuery[] manyQueries = new RawQuery[]{
      new RawQuery(true,safeInsertSchoolSQL,new String[]{"S001"}),
            new RawQuery(true,insertSchoolSQL,new String[]{"S001"}),
            new RawQuery(true,safeInsertSchoolSQL, new String[]{"S002"}),
            new RawQuery(true,insertSchoolSQL, new String[]{"S002"})
    };
    actionMultipleRawQueries(manyQueries,false,db,true,TAG+"-MQ-FAIL",true);
    logAllSchools("-STAGE003");

    /* Switch so all queries use the safe OR IGNORE so duplicates are ignored */
    for(RawQuery rq: manyQueries) {
        rq.setActionSQL(safeInsertSchoolSQL);
    }
    actionMultipleRawQueries(manyQueries,true,db,true,TAG+"MQ-WORK",true);
    logAllSchools("-STAGE004");

    actionMultipleRawQueries(new RawQuery[]{
            new RawQuery(true,"DELETE FROM school WHERE schoolId % 2 = 1",null),
            new RawQuery(true,"INSERT OR IGNORE INTO school VALUES(100,'School100')",null),
            new RawQuery(true,"UPDATE school SET schoolName = 'NEW-'||schoolName WHERE schoolId % 2 = 0",null),
    },false,db,true,TAG+"MQSTG5",true);
    logAllSchools("-STAGE005");
```

results in the log additionally containing:-

```
2022-08-22 11:53:49.598 D/DBINFO-MQ-FAIL: Beginning Transaction
2022-08-22 11:53:49.598 D/DBINFO-MQ-FAIL: Actioning Raw Query INSERT OR IGNORE INTO School (schoolName) VALUES(?) args are:
             Arg is S001
2022-08-22 11:53:49.599 D/DBINFO-MQ-FAIL: Actioning Raw Query INSERT INTO School (schoolName) VALUES (?) args are:
             Arg is S001
2022-08-22 11:53:49.600 E/SQLiteQuery: exception: UNIQUE constraint failed: School.schoolName (code 2067 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE); query: INSERT INTO School (schoolName) VALUES (?)
2022-08-22 11:53:49.600 D/DBINFO-MQ-FAIL: Action Multiple Raw Queries Exception:-
        UNIQUE constraint failed: School.schoolName (code 2067 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE)
2022-08-22 11:53:49.600 W/System.err: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: School.schoolName (code 2067 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE)
2022-08-22 11:53:49.600 W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForCursorWindow(Native Method)
2022-08-22 11:53:49.608 W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteConnection.java:1001)
2022-08-22 11:53:49.609 W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteSession.java:838)
2022-08-22 11:53:49.609 W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:62)
2022-08-22 11:53:49.609 W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:153)
2022-08-22 11:53:49.609 W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:140)
2022-08-22 11:53:49.610 W/System.err:     at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:231)
2022-08-22 11:53:49.610 W/System.err:     at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:270)
2022-08-22 11:53:49.610 W/System.err:     at a.a.so73431456javaroomcatchtryexample.AllDao_Impl.rawQueryIntoLong(AllDao_Impl.java:109)
2022-08-22 11:53:49.610 W/System.err:     at a.a.so73431456javaroomcatchtryexample.MainActivity.actionMultipleRawQueries(MainActivity.java:145)
2022-08-22 11:53:49.610 W/System.err:     at a.a.so73431456javaroomcatchtryexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:63)
2022-08-22 11:53:49.610 W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7994)
2022-08-22 11:53:49.610 W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)
2022-08-22 11:53:49.610 W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
2022-08-22 11:53:49.611 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
2022-08-22 11:53:49.611 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
2022-08-22 11:53:49.611 W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
2022-08-22 11:53:49.611 W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
2022-08-22 11:53:49.611 W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
2022-08-22 11:53:49.611 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
2022-08-22 11:53:49.612 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
2022-08-22 11:53:49.612 W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
2022-08-22 11:53:49.612 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
2022-08-22 11:53:49.612 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2022-08-22 11:53:49.612 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
2022-08-22 11:53:49.612 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
2022-08-22 11:53:49.612 D/DBINFO-MQ-FAIL: Ending Transaction.


2022-08-22 11:53:49.613 D/DBINFO-STAGE003: SchoolName is School1 ID is 1
2022-08-22 11:53:49.613 D/DBINFO-STAGE003: SchoolName is School2 ID is 2
2022-08-22 11:53:49.613 D/DBINFO-STAGE003: SchoolName is School3 ID is 3
2022-08-22 11:53:49.613 D/DBINFO-STAGE003: SchoolName is School4 ID is 4


2022-08-22 11:53:49.613 D/DBINFOMQ-WORK: Beginning Transaction
2022-08-22 11:53:49.613 D/DBINFOMQ-WORK: Actioning Raw Query INSERT OR IGNORE INTO School (schoolName) VALUES(?) args are:
             Arg is S001
2022-08-22 11:53:49.616 D/DBINFOMQ-WORK: Actioning Raw Query INSERT OR IGNORE INTO School (schoolName) VALUES(?) args are:
             Arg is S001
2022-08-22 11:53:49.617 D/DBINFOMQ-WORK: Actioning Raw Query INSERT OR IGNORE INTO School (schoolName) VALUES(?) args are:
             Arg is S002
2022-08-22 11:53:49.618 D/DBINFOMQ-WORK: Actioning Raw Query INSERT OR IGNORE INTO School (schoolName) VALUES(?) args are:
             Arg is S002
2022-08-22 11:53:49.626 D/DBINFOMQ-WORK: Setting Transaction Successful.
2022-08-22 11:53:49.626 D/DBINFOMQ-WORK: Ending Transaction.


2022-08-22 11:53:49.627 D/DBINFO-STAGE004: SchoolName is School1 ID is 1
2022-08-22 11:53:49.627 D/DBINFO-STAGE004: SchoolName is School2 ID is 2
2022-08-22 11:53:49.627 D/DBINFO-STAGE004: SchoolName is School3 ID is 3
2022-08-22 11:53:49.628 D/DBINFO-STAGE004: SchoolName is School4 ID is 4
2022-08-22 11:53:49.628 D/DBINFO-STAGE004: SchoolName is S001 ID is 5
2022-08-22 11:53:49.628 D/DBINFO-STAGE004: SchoolName is S002 ID is 6


2022-08-22 11:53:49.628 D/DBINFOMQSTG5: Beginning Transaction
2022-08-22 11:53:49.628 D/DBINFOMQSTG5: Actioning Raw Query DELETE FROM school WHERE schoolId % 2 = 1 args are:
2022-08-22 11:53:49.629 D/DBINFOMQSTG5: Actioning Raw Query INSERT OR IGNORE INTO school VALUES(100,'School100') args are:
2022-08-22 11:53:49.630 D/DBINFOMQSTG5: Actioning Raw Query INSERT OR IGNORE INTO school VALUES('1100','School100') args are:
2022-08-22 11:53:49.632 D/DBINFOMQSTG5: Actioning Raw Query UPDATE school SET schoolName = 'NEW-'||schoolName WHERE schoolId % 2 = 0 args are:
2022-08-22 11:53:49.635 D/DBINFOMQSTG5: Setting Transaction Successful.
2022-08-22 11:53:49.635 D/DBINFOMQSTG5: Ending Transaction.


2022-08-22 11:53:49.642 D/DBINFO-STAGE005: SchoolName is NEW-School2 ID is 2
2022-08-22 11:53:49.643 D/DBINFO-STAGE005: SchoolName is NEW-School4 ID is 4
2022-08-22 11:53:49.643 D/DBINFO-STAGE005: SchoolName is NEW-S002 ID is 6
2022-08-22 11:53:49.643 D/DBINFO-STAGE005: SchoolName is NEW-School100 ID is 100
```

As can be seen the first use of **actionMultipleQueries**, as expected, trapped the exception due to the UNIQUE constraint and the resultant exception.

Whilst the second use due to using `OR IGNORE` completed successfully.

The third use shows the flexibility by

- deleting Schools with an id that is an odd number, leaving only schools with even id's.
- inserts a new School named school100 with an id of 100 and does so successfully, then
- tries to insert a new school also named school100 but with an id of 1100, as `OR IGNORE` is used the duplicate is ignored.
- finally updating even number schools to prefix the school name with NEW-
- The results should be obtainable, at least for those that store the RawQuery[] in a variable rather than building it on the fly (as per the last/third use).

**Again, this is not a recommended approach**, rather it just demonstrates that you could ***"use try/catch purposefully"***

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer. I have one more question : I get some data from server to save in local database, how about this? Should I use try...catch ? My purpose is to avoid unknown crash

Comment: @NimaKhalili that is something that you should chose to do according to the requirements of the App.